# How to catch http errors and display message to user with ngrx store/effects? (angular2+)

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I'm trying to interact with my REST API endpoints within my angular 5 app utilizing ngrx.

Making a successful request is fairly straight forward and is working fine. However, if the API registers an error in the request, and wants to send my front end angular app back a message, I'm not sure on how to display the error and message to the user.

Here is my auth effect for a signin:

```
@Effect()
  authSignin = this.actions$
    .ofType(AuthActions.TRY_SIGNIN)
    .map((action: AuthActions.TrySignin) => {
      return action.payload;
    })
    .switchMap((authData: { email: string, password: string }) => {
      return this.http.post<any>(this.globals.login, authData);
    })
    .map((returnData: { message: string, auth: { token: string, user_name: string } }) => {
      this.router.navigate(['']);
      localStorage.setItem('token', returnData.auth.token);
      localStorage.setItem('user_name', returnData.auth.user_name);
      return {
        type: AuthActions.SET_AUTH,
        payload: {
          token: returnData.auth.token,
          user_name: returnData.auth.user_name,
          authenticated: true
        }
      };
    })
    .catch((err: any) => {
      console.log(err);
      return {
        type: AuthActions.AUTH_ERROR
      };
    });
```

Currently, if you send a request with the correct information, you will be returned a token / your username and everything works fine.

However, if the API wants to tell you the email/password is incorrect, I'm not sure how to register the error and tell the user. I've tried looking elsewhere for an easy to use resource, but nothing I've found seems to work.

With my code above, I'm getting a TS Compile Error:

> ERROR in src/app/auth/store/auth.effects.ts(44,12):
>
> error TS2345: Argument of type '(err: any) => { type: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '(err: any, caught: Observable<{ type: string; payload: { token: string; user_name: string; authen...'.
>
> Type '{ type: string; }' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<{}>'.
>
> Type '{ type: string; }' is not assignable to type 'ArrayLike<{}>'.
>
> Property 'length' is missing in type '{ type: string; }'.

and in the console after request:

> ERROR TypeError: You provided an invalid object where a stream was
> expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.

Once I've made a bad request, it no longer allows me to make any http requests from the same form, I have to refresh the page each time.

Hoping someone can help point me in the right direction. If you have any questions / want to see more of my code, please say!

Comment: Take a look at this, might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48595961/6294072 You need to create a disposable stream to keep it alive :) Also you need to return an Observable of your error.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the **catch** you can't send an Object. You should return an Observable like bellow

```
catch((error) => {
  console.log(error);
  return Observable.of({type: AuthActions.AUTH_ERROR});
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Observable `catch` is not the same of javascript catch you need to return an Observable or it will throw a `TypeError` since it will need to unwrap that back.

One easy way of dealing with this is to wrap your object inside an Observable create method such as `of`.

So in essence it would be

```
catch((error) => Observable.of({type: AuthActions.AUTH_ERROR}))
```